# Closed form of a sum of ratios of integers

Tags: summation, closed-form, rational-numbers, integers

I am computing in a program this sum (does it have a "name"):

$$\sum_{\alpha=2}^{K}   \frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha}$$

is there  a way to avoid the sum, term by term, and use a more compact closed form ?

Comment: See [harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

Comment: Use following asymptotic expansion for $k\gg 1$ ($15$ digits precision for $k>30$) : $$K-\gamma-\log(K+1/2)-\frac 1{24K^2}+\frac 1{24K^3}-\frac{23}{960K^4}+\frac 1{160K^5}+\frac {11}{8064K^6}+\frac 1{896K^7}$$ and compute directly $\;\displaystyle k-\sum_{j=1}^k\frac 1j\;$ (noted $k-H_k$) for small values of $k$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Raymond: that seems quite useful in practice.

Comment: Thanks Pam. It indeed is! :-) Note that the first sum will be more precise for higher values of $K$. If you need $19$ digits precision for example use the first sum for $K>100$ and the other one for smaller values of $K$. Excellent continuation!

Comment: If I fix an arbitrarily large digit precision (e.g. 700 digits) is it correct to say that, using this approximation (or a similar one), my computational effort is O(logK), or is it still a linear complexity O(K)?

Comment: For fixed (high) precision I would say (possibly wrongly...) that the first approximate solution is in $O(1)$ while the second is in $O(K)$. Btw you may obtain higher precision using more terms for example from [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series%20digamma%28n%2B1%29-ln%28n%2B1%2F2%29) (expansion at $n=\infty$). Now even using the expansion up to $K^{-13}$ you will obtain only about $100$ digits of precision for $K>10^7$. For high precision a better method is to compute the first terms and to approximate the remainder using Euler Mclaurin. I'll write this down a little later...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't, because finding a compact form for the sum is equivalent to find a compact form for the harmonic sum
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k
$$
which we know that doesn't exists. But you can approximate your sum by using
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k=\log(n)+\gamma+O(n^{-1})
$$

Comment: Thank you k1M. I was hoping that the a-1 at numerator could make any difference:-)

Comment: You're welcome....

Comment: @Pam Note that $\frac{\alpha-1}\alpha$ is just the same thing as $1-\frac1\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{\alpha=2}^{K}   \frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha}=K-\digamma^{(0)}(K+1)-\gamma$$

With

$\digamma^{(0)}$ is the derivative of the digamma function

and

$\gamma$ is the eulergamma

Comment: Very interesting. Does that F(0) boil down to something that is easier to compute than the original sum? How can I compute it in practice?

Comment: I'll look for it

Comment: No it isn't possible its a polygamma of (0,K+1) so the term: $\digamma^{0}(K+1)$ belongs together

Comment: Though it's called the digamma function, it's usually represented by the letter $\psi$ psi. Don't ask.

Answer (score 1):

In the comments I proposed following formula for $K\gg 1$ (about $15$ digits precision for $K>30$) 
$$K-\gamma-\log(K+1/2)-\frac 1{24K^2}+\frac 1{24K^3}-\frac{23}{960K^4}+\frac 1{160K^5}+\frac {11}{8064K^6}+\frac 1{896K^7}$$
and to compute directly $\,K-H_K\;$ for small values of $K$ ($H_K=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^K\frac 1i\;$ is an [harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number)).

This works well using machine precision (simple or double precision computations) but for higher precision a variant of this formula will be useful.

Let's concentrate on the evaluation of $H_K$ : the idea is to compute the $m$ first terms of $H_K$ (with $m$ much smaller than $K$) and to approximate the remaining terms $\;\displaystyle\sum_{i=m+1}^K\frac 1i\;$ using the [Euler-Maclaurin formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula#The_formula) applied to $f(i)=\dfrac 1i\;$ with $p$ [Bernoulli numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_numbers) $B_{2i}$. This gives :

$$H_K\approx\sum_{i=1}^m \frac 1i+\log\frac Km-\frac{\frac 1m-\frac 1K}2+\sum_{i=1}^p \frac{B_{2i}}{2i}\left(\frac 1{m^{2i}}-\frac 1{K^{2i}}\right)$$

This is an asymptotic expansion and the error will be smaller than the last term that is about $\dfrac{B_{2p}}{2p\;m^{2p}}$. From the asymptotic expansion of $B_{2p}$ the error will thus be of order $\,\left(\dfrac p{\pi\, e \,m}\right)^{2p}$.

You will probably have to experiment a little to find the adequate values of $m$ and $p$ for your purpose ($p$ should not be too large because of the cost of evaluation of $B_{2p}$ but clearly a larger $p$ will require a much smaller value of $m$ for the same precision).

---

[pari/gp](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/download.html) script and session :

```
h(m)=sum(i=1,m,1./i)
Ha(K,m,p)=h(m)+log(K/m)-(1/m-1/K)/2+sum(i=1,p,bernfrac(2*i)/(2*i)*(1/m^(2*i)-1/K^(2*i)))

> \p 200
realprecision = 202 significant digits (200 digits displayed)
> Ha(10^7,100,100)
time = 35 ms.
%117 = 16.695311365859851815399118939540451884249869752373080462785135954356288692174254687711603714370150288290523817663737266777337218196739075784366572290986079962307335928126443225226765412693037825657127
>  h(10^7)
time = 20,941 ms.
%118 = 16.695311365859851815399118939540451884249869752373080462785135954356288692174254687711603714370150288290523817663737266777337218196739075784366572290986079962307335928126443225226765412693054650051411
> %-%117
%119 = 1.6824394283730879816 E-188
```

The first evaluation is much faster (to $188$ digits precision here) !

Excellent experimentations,

Comment: Thanks a lot Raymond. I am going to play a bit with this with my PC. Do you have information about the "computational complexity" of this approximation ? You say "m much smaller than K". My specific question in regard is "how small" as K tends to infinity ? In particular, can we stay logarithmic (relative to K) instead of having to grow it polynomially, having fixed a given high precision? If you can add some of these (asymptotic) complexity considerations to your post it would be a lot interesting.

Comment: From the error term $\,\left(\dfrac p{\pi\, e \,m}\right)^{2p}=10^{-d}\,$ (for a precision of $d$ digits) you may observe that the precision doesn't depend of $K$ (well very little). This means that replacing $10^7$ in my gp session by another large value will return another value with nearly the same precision. The only cost **in time** depending of $K$ will thus come from the evaluation of $\log\frac Km$ and of the negative powers of $K$. This cost will depend much of your specific multiprecision package ;

Comment: concerning pari/gp it seems to be 'not to far' from $O(\log K)$.(in the range $10^6<K<10^{11}$ for $m=300$ and $p=200$ I tested). Of course this is not a proof that would involve precise evaluation of $\log$ and powers on your specific implementation. Hoping this helped anyway,

Comment: Thanks a lot Raymond. O(logK) would be really great!

Comment: @Pam: I omitted the expression for $m$ that can easily be deduced (from my last equation in the comments) to return for a fixed number of digits $d$ and $p$ binomial coefficients : $$m=\left\lceil
\frac p{\pi\,e}\;10^{\;d/(2\,p)}\right\rceil$$ Concretely for $700$ digits and for any 'large' $K$ this will require the evaluation of $m=37031$ terms for $p=100$ and $1317$ terms for $p=200$. Your next problem may thus be the evaluation of large Bernoulli numbers. Excellent continuation,